# Program Arduino Uno via Nano

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano

To keep the question short:

I'm trying to burn a bootloader on my Arduino Uno using an Arduino Uno. Could someone please tell me the pin connections? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To burn a bootloader from source Nano to target Uno make the following connections:

```
Nano.Pin   Uno.Pin

10         Reset

11         11

12         12

13         13

GND        GND
```

See here for more details: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard